# Replace non-digit characters from an array of String and return a String Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to replace non-digit characters from an array of String and return a String with digits separated by coma, actually, I made it but don't like it.

The first thing I made, was added values from the String array to the String.

Then I replaced non-digit characters from a String.

After that, I added digit values to an int array and sorted it.

Then I added all this stuff to an array of strings and separated values with commas, after that I returned it.

I would be glad for advice, thanks for attention.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {

    private static String sortedStringOfNumber(String[] string) {

        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s: string) {
            temp.append(s);
        }

        String numberOnly = temp.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        int[] numbers = new int[numberOnly.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOnly.length(); i++) {
            numbers[i] = numberOnly.charAt(i) - '0';
        }

        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        String[] result = new String[numbers.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

            result[i] = String.valueOf(numbers[i]);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            sb.append(result[i].toString());
            if (i != result.length - 1)
                sb.append(", ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrayStringData = new String[] { "1", "ab3c", "level", null, "java2s.com", "asdf 456", "Br0C0de" };

        //Should be "0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
        System.out.println("Sorted string of numbers ->\t" + sortedStringOfNumber(arrayStringData));
    }
}
```

Comment: You made it, but you don't like it? What exactly do you ask for?

Comment: It looks like trash, I want it to be cleaner.@John

Comment: This is a small program. There is probably no lag in performance. Do not try to make micro improvements. This often results in making the program harder to read. Furthermore, this site is actually not made for code reviews. If you have a specific question, this is for you. But I cannot quiet figure out what you expect to be better.

Comment: What makes you feel "it looks like trash" though? It's quite hard to judge code based on subjective "prettiness". We can be more helpful if you go into more detail on "what pattern looks not pretty and why"

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question & Answer platform. There is no question here. It would be better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should provide some example of input and expected output.  It's too much to read your code and trying to guess what the output for an input is.

Comment: no idea why the code is sorting... for "Replace non-digit characters from an array of String and return a String": `Arrays.stream(input).map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D", "")).map(s -> s.split("")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.joining(","))`  (easy to add `sorted()` if needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution would run in O(n*log n) mainly due to Arrays.sort.

Use a simple counting sort.  This would give you a runtime of O(n).

Look at the string and ignore all other non-digits.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try it this way:

```
 String sortedIntsCsv = Arrays.stream(string).map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D", "")).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sorted().mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```